# mvc3 Razor foreach loop issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I have the following code but the if statement within the loop causes the statement to fail, any ideas please?

```
@{ var count = 1; }
@foreach (var siteIcon in Model.SiteIconsList)
{
    <div class="span2">
        <a onclick="updateIcon(@siteIcon.ImageId)" href='#'>
            <img class="iconImage" src="data:Image;base64,@(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(siteIcon.ImageData)))" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
    if(count==5){
        </div>
         <div class="row-fluid">
         count=1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it was the closing divs confused razor. In order to stop this I got it working by wrapping the new opening and closing divs in an htmlstring which stopped them being parsed and I also made a correction to the counter.

```
   <div class="row-fluid">
                @{
                    var count = 1;
                    foreach (var siteIcon in Model.SiteIconsList)
                    {
                        <div class="span2">
                                <a onclick="  updateIcon(@siteIcon.ImageId)" href='#'>
                                    <img class="iconImage" src="data:Image;base64,@(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(siteIcon.ImageData)))" alt="" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        if (count == 5)
                        {
                            @(new HtmlString("</div><div class=\"row-fluid\">"))
                            count = 0;
                        }
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                }
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your divs are not properly formatted, they are closed before and opened later,
check this

```
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
```

instead you can do this

```
if(count==5){

<div class="row-fluid"> </div>
count=1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            @foreach (var siteIcon in Model.SiteIconsList)
            {
                <div class="span2">
                    <a onclick="updateIcon(@siteIcon.ImageId)" href='#'>
                        <img class="iconImage" src="data:Image;base64,@(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(siteIcon.ImageData)))" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                if(count==5){

                     <div class="row-fluid">
                     </div>
                    count=1;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you aren't incrementing the count at the end of your loop, so the condition will never be satisfied.

It would be better to change Foreach to For like so:

```
for(int i=0; i<Model.SiteIconsList.Count;i++)
```

```
                if(i==5){
                    <text></div>
                     <div class="row-fluid"></text>
                     count=1;
                }
            }
```

What message are you getting when it fails? You might need to use  to break back into html rendering mode